PC is running but no display/boot – What should I do?
I noticed this while cleaning up some dust in my PC:

Can I still use my GPU? My computer was still working this afternoon but when turning it on tonight, I see no display on the monitor. (I checked the HDMI cable, it was not loose. The LED lights that indicate when something is wrong (CPU, DRAM, VGA, BOOT) has one lit up (DRAM), but the PC is still running) Is it because of the thing in the picture or due to another part/cable? I'm not sure what to do.

The image isn't very clear. Could you describe more what we're supposed to be seeing? It appears you may have zoomed in quite a bit, or your camera isn't catching the necessary detail.

When you say the LEDs indicate a DRAM issue, is this based on your mainboard's documentation? Have you swapped/replaced/removed the RAM to see if the computer POSTs without it? Does your mainboard have a video output so you can remove the video card and try running the computer without it? Hardware diagnostics usually mean removing/swapping hardware a component at a time until you've identified the part or parts that are causing the problem. So you'll want to start doing that.

Most likely, a part was removed and did not seat in the connector correctly on replacement. Remove what you did when cleaning, check sockets for bent pins (difficult, but sometimes possible, to fix), and replace carefully, fully reseating into the socket.  Other likely causes of the issue require professional repair (e.g., electrostatic discharge or short circuit destroyed a part). As for the photo, it shows nothing useful.
